# Selenium IDE using storeText variable as id of some other field

Tags: selenium

In Selenium IDE, we have a page that writes a different number every time.  There's a checkbox on that page I need to check, whose id is 'ldev_####', where '####' is the number that changes.  Is there a way I can use the storeText command to store the number that changes each time and then somehow make that part of the id on the click command?  I tried this, and it didn't work:

```
storeText | //table[@id='xxxxx']/tbody/tr/td[5] | ldev_var
click     | id=ldev_$ldev_var
```

The id above usually comes out like this:  id=ldev_1234

it's the '1234' that changes.  Am I overthinking this, or is there an easier way to do this?

thanks so much for any help,
Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath expression to solve this problem:

```
//input[starts-with(@id,'ldev_')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm still a bit of a newbie with this stuff.  I got rid of my storeText command and modified my click command to say: click | //div[starts-with(@id,'ldev_')] but I got an "Element not found" error.  Did I put this in the wrong place? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I think you should use //table[starts-with(@id,'ldev_')] if your first expression is ok (/table[@id='xxxxx']/tbody/tr/td[5]). The results will be the ldev_XXXX table web elements

Comment: So the solution is : //table[starts-with(@id,'ldev_')]/tbody/tr/td[5]
(checked with xpath checker)

If you want to use the first one, you should use this one:
//table[starts-with(@id,'ldev_')][1]/tbody/tr/td[5]

Comment: Thanks Silverado...I was able to figure out that I needed it to be //input[starts-with(@id,'ldev_')].  That works.  Thanks so much for your time & help.

Comment: Actually the solution is: //input[starts-with(@id,'ldev_')]